# java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required still not working

Tags: javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

I have also run into some problems trying to get my JavaFX program to run. Like some of the others, I keep getting an error of `java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.` The fxml file is in the Application package.  I've tried all the remedies I've found in here, but maybe I'm missing something? Here is my code

```java
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("application/Main.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And here is the Error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:18)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: `getClass().getResource(...)` will search relative to the current class. So this is expecting `Main.fxml` to be in the `application.application` package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine the correct path for FXML files, CSS files, Images, and other resources needed by my JavaFX Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other)

Answer (score 0):

I lost an entire day battling with this issue in Netbeans. This is how I solved it : Firstly, I put the fxml file in the same package with main (though it can work even in separate packages). Secondly, I used getClassLoader() specifying the path of the file. Here's the code :`
  public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Test  = "+Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));`
```

After Running the project, here's the output : ....NetBeansProjects/JavaFXApplicationTest/dist/JavaFXApplicationTest.jar!/FXMLDocument.fxml
Note that Running the file alone was generating an error before.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
"/application/Main.fxml"
```

you just need to add a /

Answer (score -3):

Solved the problem by dragging and dropping Main.fxml in src folder.